# Is @Consumes annotation required or optional in the DELETE method Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I'm new in jersey rest service and I want to understand in this example the utility of adding `@Consumes` annotation to a delete method in this case this is the code it's work well (in a video ), is the `@Consumes` annotation optional here ? Thanks in advance

```
 @path("activities")
 public class ActivityResource {

    @DELETE
    @Path("{activityId}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Response delete(@PathParam("activityId")String activityId) {
        activityRepository.delete(activityId);
        return Response.ok().build() ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the `@Consumes` annotation optional here ?

Yes, I would even say that it is not needed as you have only one parameter and it is a `PathParam` which means that it will be extracted from the path.

The annotation `@Consumes` is used to indicate the JAX-RS implementation how to dynamically **parse/deserialize** the body of your request in order to have it as parameter in a more convenient type.

**For example:**

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/xml")
public void registerUser(User user) {
    ...
}
```

In this example, we indicate that the body of the request is of type `application/xml`, the JAX-RS implementation will then parse the body's content as an XML to finally get an instance of `User`.

**NB:** The HTTP method used has no effect on whether or not `@Consumes` is needed, only the need to parse the body matter.

Comment: In the case of I have more than one parameter it will stay optional ?

Comment: it depends on the type of your parameters, if you have only `PathParam` it will still be unnecessary

Comment: So I have to use this annotation only when I have data to deserialize in the body using POST & PUT it's like the "RequestBody" in Spring Rest Thank You

Comment: the method `POST` or `PUT` doesn't matter, it could be any method you want, the only rule is "use this annotation only when I have data to deserialize in the body"

Answer (score 1):

A `DELETE` should not be interested in anything that is in the request body. It should only identify the resource to be deleted based on the URI.

Remove the `@Consumes`, it is wrong here.

Also think about returning a HTTP status [`204 No Content`](https://httpstatuses.com/204) instead of `200 OK`. After deleting a resource, there is nothing to return. You should also remove the `@Produces` because of this.

Comment: It should be ok to use `@Produces` to support error cases where details are returned in the response body.